# R using a table of min and max values assign a segment

Tags: r, merge, max, min

I have created a segmentation based on the number of times a customer has visited.
This looks like this:

[image]

I would like to use this table to assign a group to each of the customers.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
structure(list(frequency_score = c(1L, 4L, 5L), number_of_orders = c(4263L, 
1307L, 1333L), min = c(1, 2, 4), max = c(1, 3, 146), frequency_band = c("1 - 1", 
"2 - 3", "4 - 146")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("frequency_score", 
"number_of_orders", "min", "max", "frequency_band"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: share data with dput().

Answer (score 0):

I have done this although it's more sql than R...

```
sqldf("select a.*
            , c.frequency_score as frequency_score1
            from df a 
            left join counts_frequency c
            on a.visits between c.min and c.max
            ")
```